# Upload an image using php and HTML to the cPanel

Tags: php, html, image, cpanel

Im trying to upload an image. The purpose is to add a picture on the user's profile. To achive that Im doing a simple example where I update a picture from my computer, do some checks and if the image is ok, then it update it to the 'photos' folder (inside the cpanel, public_html/Account/photos). The problem is that everything looks fine, but then when I go to that path inside the cPanel, the picture is not there. Am I writting the path wrong?

Here is the complete code:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
      <form action="/My-code/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           Select image to upload:
           <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
           <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
     $target_dir = "Account/photos/";
     $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
     $uploadOk = 1;
     echo $target_file;
     $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
     if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
         $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
         if($check !== false) {
             echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
             $uploadOk = 1;
         } else {
             echo "File is not an image.";
             $uploadOk = 0;
         }
     }
     if (file_exists($target_file)) {
         echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
         $uploadOk = 0;
     }
     if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
         echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
         $uploadOk = 0;
     }
     if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
         echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
         $uploadOk = 0;
     }
     if ($uploadOk == 0) {
         echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
     } else {
         echo "wally1  " . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
         if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])) {
              echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
          } else {
              echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
          }
     }
?>
```

Any ideas what im doing wrong? And also, is possible to do what Im trying to do right?

Thanks in advance

[image: Image of the directory]

Comment: Move upload file not working

Comment: Thanks, I changed it but is still not uploading in the cPanel..

Comment: Folder name is same as `Account` with capital A?

Comment: Yes, I copy paste it to avoid problems

Comment: did you check the rights of the folder? Another thing that won't solve your issue but will improve your code, change `$uploadOk = 1;` at the top to `$uploadOk = false;`, then remove all the `$uploadOk = 0;` commands and change `$uploadOk = 1;` where it says file is an image to `$uploadOk = true;`. At the end change `if ($uploadOk == 0)` to `if ($uploadOk)`

Comment: Alright try to upload on root instead of inside the folder  `$target_dir = "";`

Comment: If I do that apparently works. It says that the file already exists in that directory. Anyway I dont really know where is it saving it

Comment: I also checked the permisses for that folder, and its ok

Comment: File properly save on root means code is fine

Answer (score 0):

`$target_dir = "/Account/photos/";` is an absolute path from the server's root filesystem, which likely doesn't exist and the web server user, say apache, will not have the right permissions to create it.

You probably want it to be relative to your website's directory, so try dropping that first `/`

You are also not assigning `$target_file` to anything at the top of your script.

Comment: I changed it as suggested, but still not uploading the file (code eddited)

Comment: Do you have a directory Account/photos relative to where the script runs, owned by the web server user?

Comment: I just added the image of the directory, hope it helps.

Comment: Which user owns that photos directory and what permission is it set to? Can you for instance, perform: `file_put_contents('Account/photos/test.txt', 'Test Content');` ? Where does the php code live in that structure - public_html?

Comment: Its all the same user, becuase Im doing some test, so there is only one user. The php code lives in my-codes. And if I add the pictures to that specific folder,its ok. But if for instance I add a "photos" folder inside my-codes and try to add the jpg files there nothing is added.

Comment: About your suggestion I can't, I have a filter saying that ony jpg, jpeg... files are allowed.

Comment: The only answer I found is to put the upload.php inside the folders folder. Its not the best solution, cause the code should be with the code. But I cant see anything else anyway

Comment: The php code executes as a web server user, probably apache. The upload target directory should be owned by that user. You can try that file_put_contents at the top of any php file. However, as you have said the php code lives in my-codes, your `$target_dir` should be `../Account/photos/` to go up one directory to public_html first.